# Push and pop on a frozen array in Chrome not throwing an exception

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, ecma262

The following code does not seem to run as expected under Chrome, and runs differently in Firefox.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  var
  arr = Object.freeze([1, 2, 3]);

  try {
    arr.push(4);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  try {
    console.log(arr.pop());
  }catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  console.log(arr);
})();
```

I expected that the output would be:

```
Error : (for `arr.push(4)`)
Error : (for `arr.pop()`)
[1, 2, 3]
```

but when running this code on Chrome 29.0.1547.49 (Official Build 216092) beta-m, I receive the following output:

```
3
[1, 2, 3]
```

Why is there no exception? I ran this code on Firefox Nightly 26.0a1(2013-08-12), and the result is

```
TypeError: arr.push(...) is not extensible
TypeError: property arr.pop(...) is non-configurable and can't be deleted
[1, 2, 3]
```

as I had expected.

I thought about why the difference between Chrome and Firefox, then I realized that it could be because of strict mode of `pop` and `push` methods. To sum up, in Firefox (SpiderMonkey) `pop` and `push` methods are defined in strict mode, but in Chrome (V8) these methods isn't defined in strict mode.

I don't know what is the actual specification. (I read some ECMA-262 5.1th Edition, but I can't find such section.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ECMA 262 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.5) says the following of `Array.prototype.push`:

> **15.4.4.7** `Array.prototype.push ( [ item1 [ , item2 [ , … ] ] ] )`
>
> ....
>
> - Let `O` be the result of calling `ToObject` passing the this value as the argument.
> - Let `lenVal` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of `O` with argument "`length`".
> - Let `n` be `ToUint32(lenVal)`.
> - Let `items` be an internal List whose elements are, in left to right order, the arguments that were passed to this function invocation.
> - Repeat, while items is not empty
>
>   - Remove the first element from items and let `E` be the value of the element.
>   - Call the `[[Put]]` internal method of `O` with arguments `ToString(n)`, `E`, and **`true`**.
>   - Increase `n` by 1.
> - Call the `[[Put]]` internal method of O with arguments "length", n, and true.
> - Return n.

Notice how the argument 3 to `[[Put]]` is `true`. Now, `[[Put]]` is defined as

> **8.12.5** `[[Put]] ( P, V, Throw )`
>
> When the `[[Put]]` internal method of `O` is called with property `P`,
>   value `V`, and Boolean flag `Throw`, the following steps are taken:
>
> - If the result of calling the `[[CanPut]]` internal method of `O`  with argument `P` is **`false`**, then
>
>   - **If `Throw` is `true`, then throw a `TypeError` exception.**
>   - Else return.
>
> ...

`[[CanPut]]` then returns `false` among others, in the case of array if `[[Extensible]]` on `O` is `false`.

Thus, your Chrome **is in violation** of the ECMA 262 5.1 specification.

**Update:**

Chrome developers are talking about making the `push`, `pop` run under strict mode; however the difference is not just "strict" vs "non-strict" as the behaviour of `push` and `pop` is specified very specifically in the ECMA 262 5.1 specification.

Comment: Sorry. I am not good at English, your correction is helpful fot me.